# htaccess rewrite to redirect unusual ASP query to specific page

Tags: string, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, asp-classic

I have seen several good answers for how to redirect an ASP query that uses an ID, but I'm working with something a little more complicated and I don't know how to proceed.

Here's a example: 
http://www.example.com/subdir/anmviewer.asp?a=7&z=2
which should redirect to:
http://www.example.com/april-20-2004

I don't know how to handle the a and z values.  Any suggestions would be gratefully accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DocumentRoot/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^a=7&z=2$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^subdir/anmviewer\.asp$ /april-20-2004? [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: Thanks anubhava but no luck. This is a WordPres site with iTheme Security enabled, so there are several existing rewrite rules which might be conflicting with the one I added.  For instance, I removed the "block suspicious URIs" rules and tested the link again but it still goes to Page Not Found.

Comment: Is three a htaccess in subdir also? If not then place this rule as very first rule just below `RewriteEngine on` line.